# Can I ask for criticism of a paper or theory?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask for criticism or improvement advice for a paper or theory available online?

Comment: No, this would be off-topic.

Comment: However, if you have a *particular, concise, and self-contained question* (Is this known? Can you give a short proof of that lemma? Can you strengthen this statement to...?, etc.), there is a good chance you'll get a meaningful response. Just avoid vague open ended questions of the kind "What do you think of ... in general?"

Comment: Also, the question asked here should be more-or-less self-contained. Motivations such as "I want to prove [x] famous conjecture" are vacuous, as we _all_ want to prove such conjectures, but are realistic about how likely that is.